# Jboss Domain deploy reports error: no deployment content with hash XXXX is avaiable in the deployment content repository

Tags: dns, jboss7.x

I have set up a Jboss domain environment, which consists of two Jboss server, where one is a master and  another is a slave. But when I try to deploy a simple java web demo into the server group , I got the following error in the salve's log :

```
 [Server:server-one] 16:20:37,024 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (pool-1-thread-2) Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jspdemo.war")]) - failure description: "No deployment content with hash eeeabd6c922da77e90db743602e6d24ba5592ce2 is available in the deployment content repository."
```

Here is the screenshot of console management: 
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Go to your standalone.xml .

Find:

```
<deployments>
        <deployment name="xxx.war" runtime-name="xxx.war">
            <content sha1="xxxxxxx"/>
        </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Just remove it and try to restart a server.

Answer (score 4):

Search for jspdemo.war in your standalone.xml and delete the entire deployments tag. May be nice to also delete the content related to jspdemo.war in the deployments folder.

Answer (score 0):

Were you updating from CR1 and maybe are using some old configuration?
The deployment location changed in-between. Was:
jboss-as-7.1.0.CR1b\domain\content in CR1 and is
jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\domain\data\content in final.

Answer (score 0):

In Domain mode the war also needs to be removed from servergroup.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/356893 (What is use of $JBOSS_HOME/domain/data directory in JBoss EAP 6 ?)